# I have an arrway with objects, now I want to fill these objects with strings

Tags: java, arrays

DISCLAIMER: THIS IS HOMEWORK

Hi,

GOAL: Create a Flat/appartment with different rooms, which can be rented by a person (renter). I can make new renters (if there are free rooms) and delete renter when they want to leave.

What I have:

I've created a custom Array called Flat with rooms.

First, I've Created an array (no ArrayList because I know the size of the array beforehand)

```
Flat(int a) {
    rooms = new Room[a];

    for (int i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
        rooms[i] = new Room(); 
    }
}
```

Secondly, I've added a Renter object into the rooms, those will be NULL at first because I want to check if the rooms are emtpy.

```
public class Room {
renter Renter; 

    Room() {
        renter = null; 
    }
}
```

So, now I have array with rooms with renter objects that are set to null.

SECOND PART:

I have a class called Renter.

A renter must consist of name and lastname. And this data will be filled in using the scanner class. My renter class looks like this:

```
public Class Renter {

    private String name; 
    private String lastName; 

    public void setName(String name) { 
        this.name = name; 
    }

    public void setName(String lastName) { 
        this.lastName = lastName; 
    }
```

Ok so far so good:

Now I want to add a renter to a room if a room is available.

So in my Flat class, I have a method newRenter, like this:

```
void newRenter() {
       (if freeRooms > 0) {
          for (int i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
            if (rooms[i].renter == null) {
                rooms[i].renter = new Renter(); 
            }
          }
        } else {
           System.out.println("No rooms available"); 
    }
```

Now, is the part where I get lost. I don't know how I can fill this new made renter object with data using the scanner class.

**MY SOLUTION THAT DOESN'T WORK**

It feels like I should do this the "other way" arround. First create an empty object THEN fill these with the right data.

For example, in my renter Class I can have the following constructor:

```
Renter() {
    name = ""; 
    lastname = ""; 
}
```

I want this value filled with the right data. So I thought I would create setters.

```
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name; 
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
```

And then in my class where I interact with my user, I would use the scanner class and filling these setters with the right info:

```
public class userInput() {
String name;  
String lastname; 

    public static String retrieveInput() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);      
    if (input.hasNextLine()) {    
    } 
    return input.nextLine(); 
}

    public static void retrieveNameRenter() {
        System.out.println("Please give your firstname:");
        name = userInput(); 
        System.out.println("Please give your lastname:");
        lastname = userInput();

            //GIVE THE SETTERS MY INFO
            Renter.setLastname(lastname);
            Renter.setname(name);
```

To problem(s) I experience are mainly because I want to se the values of an object (which is non-static) with a static method (retrieveNameRenter).

Now my questions:

1) Does my solution makes sense?

2) If it does, how can I fix these error (I've tried a lot, different, classes, public, private etc. etc.)

```
error: non-static method setLastname(String) cannot be referenced from a static context
        Renter.setLastname(lastname);
```

Comment: Take your error and copy paste it (without specific variable names) in the search field.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot access a class instance methods in a `static` way i.e by just using the class name. You need to create an instance of the class to call the instance methods. These are incorrect statements:

```
Renter.setLastname(lastname);
 Renter.setname(name);
```

Create an instance of Renter class using new and call the methods using that instance, as mentioned here:

```
Renter renter = new Renter();
renter.setLastname(lastname);
renter.setname(name);
```

Learn more about instance and class variables and methods here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: Hmm. Yes I understand, but it doesn't work (yet). Could this be because: 
1) I've created my new Renter object in my flat class if it passed the if statement (that there is a free room available). 

2) My renter object is stored in the Flat array. 

Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You try to call a non-static method as a static method. Static method are defined for a `class` rather than for every instance of the class. You can call `setName(String name)` on an instance of `class Renter`.

Think about the next question: if you already added five renters to your room, which renter do you except to have the name set? You can do something like:

```
public static void retrieveNameRenter(Renter instanceToSet) {
    System.out.println("Please give your firstname:");
    name = userInput(); 
    System.out.println("Please give your lastname:");
    lastname = userInput();

    //GIVE THE SETTERS MY INFO
    instanceToSet.setLastname(lastname);
    instanceToSet.setname(name);  }
```

At the beginning you write that you use an array instead of `ArrayList` because you know the size beforehand. I recommend you read the docs for `ArrayList` [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).
There is a constructor that lets you specify the initial size. Be careful with `add()` and `set()`. Try:

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(10);
l.set(5, "str");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have static method ? Is it because you have `public static void main(String[] args)` method as a starting point of your application ?
In that case just create in that method an object of this class, i.e.:

```
public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Start start = new Start();
        start.go();
    }

    public void go() {
         //your code goes here, you can invoke non-static methods here
    }
}
```